# Get rid of whitespace at bottom of Mat Dialog

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, dialog

I am using Angular Material for my Angular app. Currently, I have a dialog that shows info about a post. However, there is a lot of annoying whitespace at the bottom of the dialog that I want to get rid of. How can I do this?

**Here is an image:**

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div id="postModal">
  <div mat-dialog-content id="postForm">
    <div class="bigImage">
      <img src={{imageLinks[0]}} class="postImage"/>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
  body{
    position: relative;
  }


.postImage{
  height: 80%;
  width: 100%;
}

.bigImage{
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

#postForm{
  height: 80vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: box;
}


mat-dialog-container{
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-top: 10px !important;
  padding-bottom: 0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the height from the `#postForm`. A `height: 80vh` makes it take up 80% of the height of the screen.

Since you are providing a fixed height to it, there will be empty space left if the image doesn't take up all the space.

Also your `postImage` has a height of 80%, the remaining space will be empty.

Comment: I removed the height attribute from the SCSS, but there is no difference. What should I do?

Comment: Have you shown the full code in your question? Also check in developer tool from where the white space is coming by inspecting the element.

Answer (score 0):

```
  body{  
  position: relative;  
  }  
  .postImage{  
               /* height: 80%;   this is your bug */  
  width: 100%;  
  }  
  .bigImage{     /* you don't need this level and even if use <figure></figure> not <div></div> */  
  text-align: center;  /* this means empty space on sides when text is to short to fill, this class hasn't setted width, so it should adjust to content witch is an img - block element without any wraps */
  display: block;   
  }   
  #postForm{  
  height: 80vh;       /* this one may caused problems too */  
  width: 100%;   
  display: box;      /* incorrect value */   
  }  
  mat-dialog-container{  
  /* padding-right: 30px; */    
  /* padding-left: 30px; */   
  /* padding-top: 10px !important; don't use !important instead of debugging */    
  /* padding-bottom: 0px !important; */  
  padding: 10px 30px 0;  /* nice and readable instead of 4 lines */  
  }
```

If you set strict height value don't be surprised if it keep it. Good prepared css is an investment - works properly and maintaining is plasure without headaches.

Answer (score 0):

```
.postImage{
  height: auto; or 100%
  width: 100%;
}
```

or don't give the height at all